# What is the eosio private key when running on local?

Tags: smart-contract, dapp

I was trying to test the smart contract I created in my local but I am currently blocked as I can't create a new account. As per EOS documentation, I used the command below to create a new account:

```
cleos create account eosio <account name> <public key>
```

But this command fails with the error below:

> Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
>
> Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
>
> Error Details:
>
> transaction declares authority '{"actor":"eosio","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.

I am guessing that I'm getting this error because I don't have have the eosio account's private key in my default wallet. I've been trying to find this information in the documentation but I wasn't able to. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this information is nowhere in EOS documentation, but it can be found in WAX's documentation.

```
5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3
```

Comment: It's in the official documentation https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/getting-started-guide/local-development-environment/development-wallet